# Why is my product collection on my staging site different than my live site?

Tags: sql, product-collection, magento-1.14, select

I've tidied up my post and clarified a few things for the bounty.

Magento is generating two different select queries for the same category on my staging site and live site.

**Scenario**

1. Backed up all files on live site - minus cache & sessions.
2. Created a dump of my magento database.
3. Setup staging site based on the backup files
4. Visited: mylivesite.com/cat1 and viewed the results of `(string)$_productCollection->getSelect()` (below)
5. Visited: mystagesite.com/cat1 and viewed the results of `(string)$_productCollection->getSelect()` (below)

Here is a comparison of the two SQL selects: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=zlg7h

Also, insignificant as it may be, my staging site is on an AWS RDS db.t2.small and my live site on db.m3.large.

**Stage Output**

```
SELECT 
`e`.*,
`cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
`price_index`.`price`,
`price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
`price_index`.`final_price`,
IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
    LEAST(price_index.min_price,
            price_index.tier_price),
    price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
`price_index`.`min_price`,
`price_index`.`max_price`,
`price_index`.`tier_price`,
IF(at_name.value_id > 0,
    at_name.value,
    at_name_default.value) AS `name`
FROM
    `mg_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN
    `mg_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id
    AND cat_index.store_id = 1
    AND cat_index.visibility IN (2 , 4)
    AND cat_index.category_id = '4'
    INNER JOIN
`mg_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
    LEFT JOIN
`mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
    AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '71')
    AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0
    LEFT JOIN
`mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
    AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '71')
    AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1)
```

**Live Output**

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`entity_id`,
    `e`.`type_id`,
    `e`.`attribute_set_id`,
    `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
    `e`.`name`,
    `e`.`short_description`,
    `e`.`price`,
    `e`.`special_price`,
    `e`.`special_from_date`,
    `e`.`special_to_date`,
    `e`.`small_image`,
    `e`.`thumbnail`,
    `e`.`news_from_date`,
    `e`.`news_to_date`,
    `e`.`status`,
    `e`.`url_key`,
    `e`.`required_options`,
    `e`.`image_label`,
    `e`.`small_image_label`,
    `e`.`thumbnail_label`,
    `e`.`msrp_enabled`,
    `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`,
    `e`.`msrp`,
    `e`.`tax_class_id`,
    `e`.`price_type`,
    `e`.`weight_type`,
    `e`.`price_view`,
    `e`.`shipment_type`,
    `e`.`links_purchased_separately`,
    `e`.`links_exist`,
    `e`.`equipment_needed`,
    `e`.`equipment_needed_value`,
    `e`.`garnish`,
    `e`.`glass_recommended`,
    `e`.`glass_recommended_value`,
    `e`.`howserved`,
    `e`.`howserved_value`,
    `e`.`servingsize`,
    `e`.`servingsize_value`,
    `e`.`bevtypeid`,
    `e`.`bevtypeid_value`,
    `e`.`is_healthy`,
    `e`.`is_healthy_value`,
    `e`.`giftcard_amounts`,
    `e`.`allow_open_amount`,
    `e`.`open_amount_min`,
    `e`.`open_amount_max`,
    `e`.`last_chance`,
    `e`.`last_chance_value`,
    `price_index`.`price`,
    `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
    `price_index`.`final_price`,
    IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
        LEAST(price_index.min_price,
                price_index.tier_price),
        price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
    `price_index`.`min_price`,
    `price_index`.`max_price`,
    `price_index`.`tier_price`
FROM
    `mg_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
        INNER JOIN
    `mg_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id
        AND cat_index.store_id = 1
        AND cat_index.category_id = '4'
        INNER JOIN
    `mg_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
        AND price_index.website_id = '1'
        AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
WHERE
    (e.status = 1)
        AND (e.entity_id IN ('6174' , '6568',
        '6511',
        '9370',
        '6436',
        '6304',
        '6760',
        '6742',
        '6456',
        '9906',
        '6558',
        '6461'))
```

Comment: Do you have flat product index enabled on your live site?

Comment: Use Flat Catalog Category & Use Flat Catalog Product are set to yes on both.

**Live Setting:** *Category Flat Index*, *Catalog Search Index* and *Product Flat Index*  are set to Update when Scheduled. 

**Stage Setting:** Each index listed above is set to - Update on Save.

Comment: 1) Ensure that the indexes are up to do date & clear EAV collection cache. 2) Ensure that attributes `at_name` and `at_name_default` are part of the flat tables on staging.

Comment: I don't see at_name nor at_name_default in any of the tables listed in the query.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mg_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "at_nam%"` should tell you if those attributes exist in EAV configuration.

Comment: They don't exist on the staging site nor the live one.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Check out `eav_attribute.attribute_id` = 71.

Comment: Thanks for following up @benmarks. `SELECT * FROM mg_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id  LIKE "at_nam%` Returns zero results on both live and staging sites.

Comment: @benmarks, FYI, if you have anymore guidance you can throw my way, I've setup a bounty for this issue.

Comment: Have you reindexed on the staging server? I had a similar issue while back - try disabling flat index and re-enabling if re-indexing doesn't work. Also try: Admin Panel->System->Cache Management->Rebuild Flat Catalog Category

Comment: BTW, the SELECT statements in the diffnow differ, but in the question, both are identical... Also, you said you did not transfer the sessions. If you delete all sessions on your live site and do the test again, is the result still the same?

Answer (score 9):

if magento reads from the `catalog_product_flat_*` table means that the flat products flag is set to yes and it's up to date and it's not locked.
If it reads from the `catalog_product_entity` table it means that the flat products flag is set to no or it's not up to date or is locked.
As simple as that.
If you say that you cloned the db from live to staging it means that the flag has the same value on both instances. If that's true (and it is) the flag is set to `Yes` on both instances.
based on the facts listed above I conclude that the index on your staging is not up to date or the var/lock folder is not readable/writable.
Delete the contents of var/lock, give it read/write permisions and rebuild all the indexes on staging and you should get the same selects.
Now some technical stuff.
Magento knows how where to read from depending on the result of the method   `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::isEnabledFlat()`.
The method looks like this:

```
public function isEnabledFlat()
{
    // Flat Data can be used only on frontend
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return false;
    }
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if (!isset($this->_flatEnabled[$storeId])) {
        $flatHelper = $this->getFlatHelper();
        $this->_flatEnabled[$storeId] = $flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt($storeId);
    }
    return $this->_flatEnabled[$storeId];
}
```

This means that if you are on the admin side flat tables are not used.
otherwise, the flat tables are used if `$flatHelper->isAvailable() && $flatHelper->isBuilt($storeId)` returns true.
Digging deeper in these 2 methods you will find that `isAvailable` returns true if the flag in the backend is set to yes or if the process is not running.  and `isBuild` returns true if the reindexing is finished.